# How to save the changes I made on an Excel sheet?

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, pandas

I read an Excel Sheet this way :

```
import pandas as pd
xl = pd.ExcelFile("Path\file_name.xlsx")
xl.parse("Sheet_name")
```

and now I make some changes, for example I fill all null values with string "NA"

```
df = df.fillna("NA")
```

now I wish to write back the changes to the original Excel file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply write the changed data to the existing file using [`to_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html):

```
df.to_excel("Path\file_name.xlsx", "Sheet_name")
```

Comment: this is fine, but I want to write back say, only one specific column, and not rewrite the entire document, is this possible?

Comment: you can add additional sheets to the excel file (see the `to_excel` documentation for an example), but I don't think, that it is possible to write single columns.

Answer (score 0):

I would work with CSV files if you have large data sets.

1. save excel as .csv
2. data = pd.read_csv('name.csv')
3. data.to_csv('name.csv')