# pd.ExcelWriter not writing to Excel file

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe

I am trying to copy and paste several dataframes I've created onto an excel file (which is also created within the same code, in a previous loop). I have several worksheets within this excel workbook, where, depending on the dataframes, the code will write to the appropriate worksheet. Here is the main loop:

```
for filename_out in os.listdir(output_directory):
    if filename_out.endswith(".xlsx"):
        file_path_out = os.path.join(output_directory, filename_out)
        wb = load_workbook(file_path_out)
        
        summary_sheet = wb['VCC_Summary']

        # Write basic info to specified cells
        summary_sheet['G4'] = proj_name
        summary_sheet['G5'] = proj_no
      
        for period_name, period in time_periods.items():
            for key, fin_data in fin_data_dict.items():
                    period, dir_num = key
                    # Check if the current key has not been processed
                    if key not in processed_keys:
                        target_sheet = get_target_sheet(dir_num)
                        # Check if a target file is determined
                        if target_sheet and period == period_name:
                            try:
                                ws = wb[target_sheet]
                                # Determine rows and columns to populate
                                start_row = rows_to_pop(period_name)
                                start_col = cols_to_pop(dir_num)
                                # Call the function to populate the worksheet
                                pop_sheet(ws, fin_data, start_row, start_col, period_name, dir_num)
                                processed_keys.add(key)
                            except PermissionError as err:
                                print(f">>>>>>>Permission error occurred for file '{file_path_out}': {err}")
                                break
                            except Exception as err:
                                print(f">>>>>>>>An unexpected error occurred: {err}")
                                continue
        wb.save(file_path_out)          
        wb.close()
```

And here is where I use ExcelWriter:

```
def pop_sheet(ws, fin_data, start_row, start_col, period_name, dir_num):
    col_letter = get_column_letter(start_col)

    # Print information about the cell being populated
    print(f"Populating column {col_letter} in worksheet {ws.title} at {start_row} with {fin_data.head(2)}"
        f"for period_name: {period_name}, movement/approach: {dir_num}")
    
    # Specify the starting cell for the DataFrame
    start_cell = f"{col_letter}{start_row}"

    # Write the DataFrame to the Excel file starting from the specified cell
    with pd.ExcelWriter(file_path_out, mode='a', engine = 'openpyxl', if_sheet_exists='overlay') as writer:
        fin_data.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=ws.title, startrow=start_row-1, startcol=start_col-1, header=False, index=False)
```

The code runs without issues, as it is able to determine which worksheet to go to and what row/col to populate (sample):

> Populating column AI in worksheet Eastbound_VCC at 109 with
>
> M.Cycle  Auto   0   0  Bus   0   0   0   0  Truck   0   0  Bike Time
>
> 19:00        0    57 NaN NaN    0 NaN NaN NaN NaN      1 NaN NaN     7
>
> 19:15        2    44 NaN NaN    1 NaN NaN NaN NaN      2 NaN NaN     9
>
> for period_name: Night, movement/approach: 2

but fails to actually write to my worksheets in the excel workbook. I suspect it might have something to do with how I'm writing pd.ExcelWriter or .to_excel, or it could be a loop logic error in my main loop. Without the code raising any errors, I can't confirm anything. How should I approach this?

Comment: In the example given, you are writing to column AI. There is a SO topic that suggests you can't do single columns - the whole sheet is overwritten. Any chance you are getting a sheet with only AI filled, or is it an empty sheet altogether, or an empty workbook altogether? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17312352/how-to-save-the-changes-i-made-on-an-excel-sheet

Comment: The ref says "Once a workbook has been saved it is not possible to write further data without rewriting the whole workbook." Maybe a flow/loop problem ... any chance you're running more than once on the same sheet? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html

Comment: @Denton Thomas, The code is using ExcelWriter in append mode (which means the Engine has to be Openpyxl). The code can write whatever data it likes, 1 cell , 1 column or whatever, just so long as the XLSX file 'file_path_out' already exists. Also multiple writes can be done to the same or different Sheet using 'to_excel' with the same 'writer' or with a new writer. Ace ; Having said that I don't see any issues, your code on the face of it does write the DataFrame to the Sheet.

Comment: Since you appear to be opening the workbook also in Openpyxl for the 'ws' object are you saving the Openpyxl workbook later and inadvertently overwriting the workbook thus losing what ExcelWriter previously added? Or otherwise certain you are looking at the right XLSX file and Sheet. You can run just that function 'pop_sheet' alone with some dummy data, it will work. Or create a test XLSX file and change the ExcelWriter to write to that file instead as a test.

Comment: @DentonThomas, to address your first comment, the excel workbook im writing to is a template where I process all the datasets for further analysis. After running the code, nothing is written to the entire workbook, aside from a few cells where I write some basic info about the data, but that's exclusive of the pd.ExcelWriter/ .to_Excel function

Comment: @moken, the way the code is setup: the code is meant to iterate over each key-value pair of datasets in my fin_data_dict dictionary and then populate the appropriate sheet with said data. Once it iterates over the entire dictionary, the (template) workbook then saves and closes.

Comment: So at the end of your code you are overwriting what pop_sheet adds. Though I would expect the permission error if you are running this in Windows opening the same file in Openpyxl and ExcelWriter. Either way you should use only the writer to add data even if you are wanting to use Openpyxl commands to do it.